# Disable laravel debugbar

Tags: laravel

I put this line on my .env file on my laravel application

```
DEBUGBAR_ENABLED=false
APP_DEBUG=false
```

But the app debug bar is still showing on the frontend?
How can I remove this?

[image]

Comment: `php artisan cache:clear`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just try this

Navigate to `app/Providers/AppServiceProvider.php`
Put this code `\Debugbar::disable();`

```
class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    public function boot()
    {
        \Debugbar::disable(); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you wanna connect in skype? I can help you anytime

Comment: Yeah of course! it's my pleasure. please give me your skype id. i will add you.

Comment: My skype ID: jesus.erwin.suarez143

Comment: Also anyone would want my help you can add me anytime and message me anytime.

Answer (score 0):

Your configurations are probably cached. Otherwise, setting `APP_DEBUG=false` should have been enough.

Try clearing the config cache with:

```
php artisan config:clear
```